# ANTLR 4 include one DSL input script into other DSL input script and call functions from imported DSL input script

Tags: java, antlr4

I want to do some common operations and I have added those to my master DSL script. Now for every DSL script I want to include a master DSL script into it and use functions/objects from it (e.g. as a helper dll/jar).

DSL1.txt

```
// other stuff
function MyOperation()
{
    // do stuff
    return result:
}
// other stuff
```

DSL2.txt

```
import DSL1;
// other stuff
var result = MyOperation()
UtilizeResult(result);
// other stuff
```

> My questions are:

1. Does  ANTLR provides such facility ?
2. If so how to do it ?